# Python script does not recognize pipe symbol |

Tags: python-2.7

I want to execute the linux command cksum, pipe it to cut to extract the 1st field:
cksum test_file.txt | cut -d ' ' -f -1
but Python does not recognize the PIPE symbol '|'

---

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
output = 
Popen(["cksum", "test_file.txt", "| cut -d ' ' -f 1"],stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]    
print output
```

---

### Output:

```
MacBook-Pro:prompt$ python cut_output.py

cksum: | cut -d ' ' -f 1: No such file or directory
3691605422 51 test_file.txt

MacBook-Pro:prompt$
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add `shell=True'. However, it is recommended not to do that as it can be a major security risk if Popen command is using user input. More information about risk [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)

```
output = Popen(["cksum", "test_file.txt", "| cut -d ' ' -f 1"],shell=True,stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Program hang when I added "shell=True"

Comment: @user1972031 Really? I don't have access to OSX but it works fine on Windows. Try executing simple `ls` command and see if it works.

Comment: @user1972031 verify that `test_file.txt` actually exists. Because if it doesn't exists, your code doesn't check for `stderr` which I think is the reason your system freezes up